# Visual Studio Code git push access denied

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a NAS with my git repositories.
With pycharm I'm able to push, pull, clone etc from this NAS repo

However when adding the NAS to git interface in Visual Studio Code I'm not asked for the password and the access is denied.

`ssh://user@192.168.0.120/volume1/git_repos/my_app`

```
> git push NAS master
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
xxxx@192.168.0.120: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I also tried to put the password in the url like: `ssh://user:password@192.168.0.120/volume1/git_repos/my_app`

How can I get VS code to ask for the password?

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command line `git config user.password "your password"` to set your password and then try again.